# Ubuntu block all outgoing connection except squid proxy traffic

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, squid, ufw

i have ubuntu 14 server and i blocked all outgoing connection using ufw

```
ufw default deny outgoing
```

and i installed squid 3 as a proxy, i want make something like a bridge, any out going connection that can go out, go out through squid and any other connection will be blocked.

i used

```
ufw allow out 3128
```

but its not working.

how can i do that?

Comment: You should be limiting incoming traffic to the squid server, not outgoing.  You blocked squid from being able to access things (assuming these changes were done on the server running squid, you didn't specify where these rules are).

Comment: the server is hacked and used to brute force external domains using outgoing connections, so i blocked all outgoing connection and i will allow only via squid

Comment: You need to restore the server from backups and then work on updating the server. For limiting connections per-process, you can look at iptables `owner` match module, where you can apply IPTables rules for single processes.